# Inquire members of a struct or class

Tags: c++

If you don't have access to the source code of a struct or class, is there a way to know the members of that struct or class? Specifically, i want to know the names, order, and data types of the members.

Comment: No, that's not possible. The names are part of the source code only, so if you have no source code, there are no names.

Comment: *If* the binary is compiled with debug symbols then you can extract some information and names from there and demangle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The language feature that you describe is called *reflection*. C++ has no support for reflection.

It is of course possible to maintain the information about classes and members and such in an external structure. Using a preprocessor, it is possible to build a system that allows defining a class and its reflection metadata without repetition.

---

There are proposals to add (static) reflection to the language: [N4428](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4428.pdf), [4447](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4447.pdf), [N4451](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4451.pdf), [SG 7](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/reflection) Hopefully reflection will become part of C++ in the future.